# Uglify-js from command line doesn't mangle variable names

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

This is similar question to this [Uglify-js doesn't mangle variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959154/uglify-js-doesnt-mangle-variable-names) but I run uglify-js from command line, I've try to call with --mt option like this:

```
 uglifyjs -o jquery.terminal.min.js --comments --mt -- jquery.terminal.js
```

but I've got this as result:

```
(function(ctx){var sprintf=function(){if(!sprintf.cache.hasOwnProperty(arguments[0])){sprintf.cache[arguments[0]]=sprintf.parse(arguments[0])}return sprintf.format.call(null,sprintf.cache[arguments[0]],arguments)};
```

but on the [site](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl//uglifyjs) I've got this as result:

```
!function(a){function d(a){return Object.prototype.toString.call(a).slice(8,-1).toLowerCase()}function e(a,b){for(var c=[];b>0;c[--b]=a);return c.join("")}var b=function(){return b.cache.hasOwnProperty(arguments[0])||(b.cache[arguments[0]]=b.parse(arguments[0])),b.format.call(null,b.cache[arguments[0]],arguments)};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is undocumented (in README on github) option `--mangle`:

```
uglifyjs -o terminal.min.js --comments --mangle -- jquery.terminal-0.10.7.js
```

Comment: It actually is documented [in the UglifyJS2 repo](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), it's just not in UglifyJS1's